# ModX Evolution PHP in Resource Content

Tags: modx

I am having trouble integrating php into my resources (pages). HTML is not a problem but when I place any php code in the resource it gets ignored. Am I missing something here or does ModX not support PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MODX does indeed support PHP, big-time. But in MODX, PHP goes in "snippets", and the snippets are referenced in resources like this: [[mySnippet]]. Put PHP directly into a resource and it will be ignored.

More in the documentation: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/Evo1/Adding+Snippets

Comment: Yes. And this is a good thing. Especially when you have multiple user / user groups maintaining the site.You can lock these snippets to be only accessible to the admin. So people who edit the content can not mess around on your server by dropping uncontrolled php code. php is very powerful and allows file and database access.